# How to group consecutive numbers having the same size

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to group consecutive integers in column 'a', having the same number of counts or rows under a new column 'id'. Given a dataframe,

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,1,2,0,1,2,3,0,1,2], 'b':[2,10,24,56,90,1,3,4,9,10]})
print(df)
```

desired output

```
   a   b  id
0  0   2   1
1  1  10   1
2  2  24   1
3  0  56   2
4  1  90   2
5  2   1   2
6  3   3   2
7  0   4   1
8  1   9   1
9  2  10   1'
```

I am still working on it. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So does the column `b` have any role here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, I'm assuming column `b` is not relevant here:

```
import more_itertools as mit
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,1,2,0,1,2,3,0,1,2], 'b':[2,10,24,56,90,1,3,4,9,10]})
groups = [list(j) for j in mit.consecutive_groups(df['a'])]
#[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2]]

group_dict = {}
ids = []
counter = 0
for g in groups:
  group = tuple(g) #(0, 1, 2)
  if group not in group_dict:
    counter += 1
    group_dict[group] = counter

  #[group_dict[group]] * len(group) -> [1, 1, 1]
  ids.extend([group_dict[group]] * len(group))

#group_dict -> {(0, 1, 2): 1, (0, 1, 2, 3): 2}
df['id'] = ids
```

Output:

```
    a   b   id
0   0   2   1
1   1   10  1
2   2   24  1
3   0   56  2
4   1   90  2
5   2   1   2
6   3   3   2
7   0   4   1
8   1   9   1
9   2   10  1
```

The `more_itertools` can be found [here](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools)